# Inequality remain true if we pass to the limit?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Say we have $$X \geq \sum_{k=1}^{n} F(k) $$

Does it follow that the inequality remain true if we pass to the limit

$$X \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} F(k) $$

Given that the $F$'s are all non negative?

Comment: Surely it depends on $n$ if $X$ is going to be greater than or equal to the sum of $F$s. If the sum is divergent then taking the limit to infinity gives a value of infinity for the sum, in which case $X \geq \infty$ doesn't make sense

Comment: If the first inequality is true for all $\;n\;$ then yes: in the limit the inequality remains.

Comment: It is true for _weak_ inequalities (e.g. $\leq$ or $\geq$). Be aware, that this is not true for strict inequalities (e.g. $<$ or $>$), that is, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}.\ X > \sum_k^n F(k)$ does _not_ imply $X > \sum_k^\infty F(k)$.

Comment: can you explicit a counter-example for strict ineq ?

Comment: @Citizen Take any convergent sum of strictly positive elements, e.g. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} =: X$, and then $X > \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$ for all $n$, with trivial equality for $\infty$.

Comment: @dtldarek I have [pi(x)-li(x) < g(x)] and g(x)=constantC when x->infinity, then if I do [x->infinity (pi(x)-li(x)) < x->infinity g(x)] then is this followed ::> [x->infinity (pi(x)-li(x)) < constantC ]

Comment: @DonAntonio I have [pi(x)-li(x) < g(x)] and g(x)=constantC when x->infinity, then if I do [x->infinity (pi(x)-li(x)) < x->infinity g(x)] then is this followed ::> [x->infinity (pi(x)-li(x)) < constantC ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your inequality is true for all $n$, then you can take the limit and get the same inequality is true for the infinite series. Of course, if $X$ is a real number, then this also implies the infinite series must be convergent if $F$ is non-negative. You don't need $F$ to always be non-negative either, and the same result holds (inequality holds for the infinite series if it holds for all $n$, or else the series is not convergent).